# How to dynamically fill (associative) array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

What i need is, that based on the value of changepos (let's call this value N, i want to fill in the Nth position of punkt in the racks element.

Example firebug output of a value in racks

```
PMS02
    Object { punkt=[3], label="slow one"}

label
    "slow one"

punkt
    [Object { x="1", y="3"}, Object { x="1", y="4"}, Object { x="1", y="5"}]

0
    Object { x="1", y="3"}

1
    Object { x="1", y="4"}

2
    Object { x="1", y="5"}
```

JS Code:

```
changePos= 4; // 4 is an example here
if(!(trimdevID in racks))
{
    alert("Defining...");
    document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim()
    racks[trimdevID] = {
        label: document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim(),
        punkt: [{
            x: $(this).index(),
            y: $(this).parent().index()}]}
}
```

What i tried:

```
if(!(trimdevID in racks))
{
    alert("Defining...");
    document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim()
    racks[trimdevID] = {
        label: document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim(),
        punkt: [
            for(var i=0;i<changepos-1;i++){
                {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0}
            }
            {
                x: $(this).index(),
                y: $(this).parent().index()}
        ]}
}
```

Comment: What values do you actually need to change? `label`? the whole `punkt` or just one element from it?

Comment: Just one element from punkt, on the nth(changepos) position. I also figured it'd be safer to define the others as 0, What i mean with this is: if i need for example to change the 2nd element, that i would fill in the 1st as {x:0,y:0}.

Comment: is really working that `for` cycle inside of "What I tried" code?? :O

Comment: @BeNdErR In python maybe, in js no way =)

Comment: nope, getting a syntax error :(

Comment: ofcourse it's not working! you can't use `for` inside an array :D, in JS (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `for` loop in an array literal. Use a loop to assign to the array elements.

```
if(!(trimdevID in racks))
{
    alert("Defining...");
    var label = document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim();
    var punkt = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < changepos-1; i++) {
        punkt[i] = {x: 0, y: 0};
    }
    punkt[changepos] = {
        x: $(this).index(),
        y: $(this).parent().index(),
    };
    racks[trimdevID] = {
        label: label,
        punkt: punkt
    };
}
```

You also had a call to `document.getElementById().value.trim()` that wasn't doing anything with the result. I changed it to set a variable and then use that later in the object creation.

Comment: Thanks dude, exactly what i was looking for, with this i'm also able to leave out the for loop and just put it in the position straight away while the ones underneath will be undefined! thanks

Comment: Also changed the ; after this indexes to 
racks[trimdevID].punkt[changingPos] =  {
       x: $(this).index(),
       y: $(this).parent().index()
       }

Answer (score 0):

```
changePos= 4; 4 is an example here
if(!(trimdevID in racks))
{
    alert("Defining...");
    document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim()
    racks[trimdevID] = {
        label: document.getElementById('devLabel').value.trim(),
        punkt: []
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < changePos /* -1 */; i++)
        racks[trimdevID][punkt][i] = {x:0, y:0};
    racks[trimdevID][punkt][changePos /* -1 */] = {
        x: $(this).index(),
        y: $(this).parent().index()
    }    
}
```

Decide whether you need that -1.